Is there a way to simulate what deployed bytecode would look like by having the bytecode without actually deploying it on blockchain?
I have an upgradable contract that I want to upgrade if it is not having the latest code. I know hardhat handles it by storing what has been deployed previously in a file, but I don't want to do that and want to rely on on-chain data.
I can get the on-chain bytecode, but it is "deployed" bytecode which I don't have off-chain, I only have the "creation" bytecode. I was wondering is there a way to convert the "creation" bytecode to "deployed" bytecode?
